# How to change elastic search service uri with authentication in c#.net?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I have implemented elasticsearch in c#.net, now I want to changes or customise the  service URI that is http://localhost:9200, please help.

Comment: Please share some of the code or some information what you've already tried.

Comment: pleases, add more info to your question,

Comment: Elasticsearch does not provide any authentication out the box. Are you looking for something like [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield)  or [Search Guard](https://floragunn.com/searchguard/) ?

Answer (score 0):

I you are looking to secure your elasticsearch cluster, then i would recommend elastic security product [shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield) which takes very good care out of the box fir securing the cluster with ssl, authentication , authorisation, rule/user/index based authentication and authorisation rules.It also has the ability to hook-up with Active Directory.But the support and forum for the advanced security topologies are limited on discussions forum.

But for simple securing the cluster with ssl and authentication i would recommend a web server proxy over your cluster 9200 port , with authentication.I once used nginx to secure the cluster as shield was a paid product then.I am attaching few links , hope they will help.

[Secure ELK with nginx.](http://blog.eagerelk.com/securing-elasticsearch-using-nginx-as-a-proxy/)

[Tricks with elastic and nginx](https://www.elastic.co/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx)